# Outlook 2013 crashing on print

Tags: printing

I have a user complaining of her outlook 2013 not responding when she tries to print an email.

This has been fine for years and now is having issues.

Doesn't seem to matter whether the email has any embedded images or not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Since i am not eligible to comment i am posting my answer. But your query requires many details like are you able to print from any other office application, Is it only emails? What about PDF or any other documents?

Try these:

- Check your email signature if broken or corrupted.
- Reinstall the driver and make sure if the driver is completely removed.
- In Outlook try to disable addins/later in safe mode if you can..
- Disable printer status notification in printer settings.
- Open outlook in safe mode, click on Click Start > in search bar > type - outlook /safe
- You must have missed the notification of update. Check if any and update.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, it was the printer driver. Thanks so much